# Elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_p$

Tags: number-theory

Please help me to solve this question:

Suppose that $ \mathbb{F}_P$ be an field of order $P$, where $P$ is an Prime number which $ P \equiv 2 \ \pmod 3$. What is  the number of points $\ x,y \ \in \mathbb{F}_P \ $ such that $ y^2 = x^3 + 1 $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*: If $p\equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then $(3, p-1)=1$ so $x \mapsto x^3$ is an automorphism of $\mathbf F_p^\times$ (and in particular, a bijection).

Comment: There's pretty much no more tips other than the complete answer, @Masoud

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand this solution.

Comment: @Masoud My pleasure.